# Is there a way to have different "androidTest.java.srcDirs" for each buildType in gradle?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, source-sets, android-build-type

I Have a requirement to execute android test cases for each build type. So "androidTest.java.srcDirs" will have different values for each build type.

For buildType 1 :

androidTest.java.srcDirs = ['tests/intrumentation1']

For buildType 2 :

androidTest.java.srcDirs = ['tests/intrumentation2']

I don't want to use flavours here for different reasons. 
            debug {
               androidTest.java.srcDirs = ['tests/debug']
           }
           alpha {
               androidTest.java.srcDirs = ['tests/alpha']
           }
In this case first one is always overridden by the next.

Any idea how to declare it for each buildType so that it should not override by the other.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use different folders for each buildType or flavors

- For flavor1

  ***Location src/androidTestFlavor1/***
- For flavor2

  ***Location src/androidTestFlavor2/***
- For Debug

  ***Location src/androidTestDebug/***
- For Alpha

  ***Location src/androidTestAlpha/***

Comment: Hi, I don't want to use flavor here for various reasons.edited my post for better clarity

Comment: Check the answer. The same way is valid for each BuildType. Use `src/androidTestDebug/`,  `src/androidTestAlpha`

Comment: In this case, you are trying to keep separate location for each variant. But all the tests will be included for each build type. isn't it??

Comment: It is the same thing. It is just the default srcDir. Declaring different srcDirs in build.gradle you are just overriding these values.